# Undefined control sequence \draw in pgfplots axis

Tags: pgfplots, compiling

I'm plotting a simple sine wave with pgfplots, but when I try and add an annotation with \draw compilation fails:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.161                                   \draw
                 (axis cs:pi.0) -- (axis cs:pi,2);
```

The code for the graph is:

```
\node at (0.4, -3) {
                                \begin{axis}[
                                        width=2.8cm,
                                        trig format plots=rad,
                                        axis lines = middle,
                                        axis line style={-},
                                        enlargelimits,
                                        ticks = none,
                                        clip=false
                                        ]
                                        \draw (axis cs:pi,0) -- (axis cs:pi,2);
                                        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,blue] {sin(x-(4*pi/4))};
                                \end{axis}
                        };
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have pfgplots version 1.16

Edit:

This is part of a bigger tikzpicture diagram:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{center}
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.9\paperwidth, max height = 0.8\paperwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \newcommand\xscale{2.5}
\foreach \xpos in {0,...,4} {
                                % weight
                                \node [circle, draw] (w\xpos) at (\xscale*\xpos, -2) {\small{$w_\xpos$}};

                        }

\node at (0.4, -3) {
                                \begin{axis}[
                                        width=2.8cm,
                                        trig format plots=rad,
                                        axis lines = middle,
                                        axis line style={-},
                                        enlargelimits,
                                        ticks = none,
                                        clip=false
                                        ]
                                        \draw (axis cs:pi,0) -- (axis cs:pi,2);
                                        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,blue] {sin(x-(4*pi/4))};
                                \end{axis}
                        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach is an unsuccessful attempt to nest `tikzpicture`s, which should strictly be avoided. Instead of `\node at (0.4, -3) {
                                \begin{axis}[` use `\begin{axis}[at={(0.4,-3)}]...`. Please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` if you need further input.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ah I see. I have the axis within a tikzpicture because it's part of a much wider diagram. The full thing is a few hundred lines, I'll try and add a minimal example

Comment: Your document runs through on my machine if I make the [above-mentioned changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507279/undefined-control-sequence-draw-in-pgfplots-axis?noredirect=1#comment1281773_507279) and add `\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{frame}` before `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have seen the complete working code in the answer, there is no point in keeping it, so I deleted it.